# Homeomorphism of Quotient Space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I am relatively new to topology and thought one should be able to prove the following:
Let $X = A \cup B$ be a topological space and $A,B \subset X$ (Maybe we need them to be closed subspaces?). Then $X/A \cong B/(A \cap B)$.

This at least seems pretty intuitively, but i do not really know how to prove that. A hint/solution would be amazing!

I tried something along the lines of:

Since $X = A \cup B$, the identity on X yields a homeomorphism $X \cong A \cup B$. This induces a homeomorphism $X/A \cong (A \cup B)/A$. Now I would like the union to respect quotients, such that $(A \cup B)/A \cong A/A \cup B/(A \cap B)$. Now the left space is a singleton and i kind of get what I want.

Comment: This is definitely a good question.. I keep hearing that topological spaces does not behave well with respect to quotient.. So, the analogue of group isomorphism theorem seems less likely to hold in case of topological spaces.. what are your thoughts on this? Have you tried anything? It would be easier to help you from the place where you got stuck...

Comment: I‘ll add an idea to the question

Comment: Should mean that you do not identify anything. So A/empty set = A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first go back to the definition. If $A$ is a subset of $X$, let $\sim_A$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by
$$
  x \sim_A y \iff \text{$x =y$ or ($x\in A$  and $y \in A$)}
$$
This is well-defined, even if $A$ is the empty set. Now, the quotient space $X/A$ is by definition $X/{\sim_A}$. Let $0$ denote the the equivalence class $[A]$ of $\sim_A$. Then, as a set,
$$
  X/{\sim_A} = \begin{cases}
  X & \text{if $A$ is empty}\\
  (X - A) \cup \{0\} & \text{if $A$ is nonempty}
\end{cases}
$$
The open subsets of $X/{\sim_A}$ are the subsets of $X-A$ open in $X$ and the subsets $U \cup \{0\}$ such that $U \cup A$ is open in $X$.

Back to your question. Since $X = A \cup B$, one gets $X - A = B - (A \cap B)$. Thus, as sets, $X/A$ and $B/(A \cap B)$ are both equal to $B$ if $A \cap B$ is empty and to $(B - (A \cap B)) \cup \{0\}$ otherwise. They are also isomorphic as topological spaces: the open sets are in both cases the sets $U$ or $U \cup \{0\}$ such that $U \cup (A\cap B)$ is open in $B$.

Comment: Awesome answer! Seems like I was not too far off with my idea; just needed a bit more formalism to realize it

Comment: @JohnBenwell you should accept an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Yanko Thanks for reminding me.